# Параллельное взаимодействие со Stream'ами одного Socket'а

Tags: многопоточность, сокет, потоки-данных

Нужна ли синхронизация для параллельного захвата входящего и исходящего `Stream`'а одного `Socket`'а разными `Thread`'ами?

Можно ли параллельно работать с входящим и исходящим `Stream`'ом одного `Socket`'а?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С точки зрения системы, понятие потока отсутствует (система сама предоставляет планировщик потоков юзермодовским программам). Так что с точки зрения системного понятия socket вопрос некорректен.

А с точки зрения объекта `Socket` некоторого языка программирования — это зависит от самого языка программирования (точнее, от реализации его системной библиотеки). В C#, например, [`Socket` потокобезопасен.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_9)